# GraphQL disable filtering if filter variable is empty

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, gatsby, contentful

I have a Gatsby GraphQL query for a list of posts ordered by date and filtered by category.

```
{
  posts: allContentfulPost(
    sort: {fields: [date], order: DESC},
    filter: {category: {slug: {eq: $slug}}}
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        title {
          title
        }
        date
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Right now when `$slug` is the empty string `""`, I get

```
{
  "data": {
    "posts": null
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get all posts instead?

Comment: Could you try setting `$slug` to `null` instead of `""` in that case?

Comment: @FabianSchultz I did. Same result unfortunately, both with and without quotes around `null`.

Comment: did you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: Not really. It ceased to be a problem for me because for unrelated reasons I opted to always query all posts and do the filtering on the fly with JS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the regex filter to your advantage. If you pass an empty expression, then all posts will be returned because everything will match.

```
query Posts($slugRegex: String = "//"){
  posts: allContentfulPost(
    sort: {fields: [date], order: DESC},
    filter: {category: {slug: {eq: $slugRegex}}}
  ) {
    # Rest of the query.
  }
}
```

By default, all posts will be returned (the `$slugRegex` is an empty regex if nothing was passed). When the `$slugRegex` becomes a meaningful expression, then only matching posts will show up.

As for passing the value, I'm assuming you're using `gatsby-node.js` to create pages. In that case, it's as simple as that:

```js
// gatsby-node.js

exports.createPages = async ({ actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  // Create a page with only "some-slug" posts.
  createPage({
    // ...
    context: {
      slugRegex: "/some-slug/"
    }
  })

  // Create a page with all posts.
  createPage({
    // ...
    context: {
      // Nothing here. Or at least no `slugRegex`.
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot figuring out a solution. In my case, I used a regex too but in the filter I've use the term `regex` instead of `eq`, so based on your example it's: `filter: {category: {slug: {regex: $slugRegex}}}`

Answer (score 2):

If anyone requires a solution for other systems than Gatsby this can be accomplished using `@skip` and `@include`.

```
fragment EventSearchResult on EventsConnection {
  edges {
    cursor
    node {
      id
      name
    }
  }
  totalCount
}

query Events($organizationId: UUID!, $isSearch: Boolean!, $search: String!) {
  events(condition: { organizationId: $organizationId }, first: 100)
    @skip(if: $isSearch) {
    ...EventSearchResult
  }
  eventsSearch: events(
    condition: { organizationId: $organizationId }
    filter: { name: { likeInsensitive: $search } }
    first: 100
  ) @include(if: $isSearch) {
    ...EventSearchResult
  }
}
```

Then in your client code you would provide search and isSearch to the query and get your events like:

```js
const events = data.eventsSearch || data.events
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with this query, even @skip/@include directives won't help because you can't apply them on input fields.

I would suggest to either adjust the server side logic so that null in the 'eq' field will ignore this filter or either to edit the query being sent (less favorable imo).

It seems that the graphql schema that you work against lacks the filtering support you need..